# Can't get correct width when loading font locally

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, fonts

I have just started creating a small tool to preview (e-mailed) WhatsApp chat logs. If you have noticed, position of the time stamps of message bubbles varies depending on the length of the message.

[image]

To get the correct positioning, first, I need to get the accurate length/width of the message (text) in pixels. I have a custom function for that, and it is working fine.

I'm using Open Sans for the font and loading it from an external source using `link` tag. With this setup, I get the correct widths of the message bubbles, but if I try to load the font locally, I get incorrect widths.

Loaded externally:

```js
$(".message").each(function () {
    console.log(this, this.clientWidth);
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    background: gainsboro;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.message {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 275px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="message">Hi!</div>
<div class="message">Hello, World!</div>
<div class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
<div class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
```

Loaded locally:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("OpenSans-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
}
```

results in:

[image]

I tried loading the font in different formats (woff2, etc.) but still had the same problem. Once I hit the rock bottom, I tried logging the widths with a timeout, and it worked.

```
$(".message").each(function () {
    console.log(this, this.clientWidth);
});

console.log("with timeout:");

setTimeout(function () {
    $(".message").each(function () {
        console.log(this, this.clientWidth);
    });
}, 100);
```

[image]

Why is this happening? Must I use timeout to get the correct width? How come the problem doesn't occur when the font is loaded externally?

<sub>This might be a Chrome spesific issue. I tried FireFox and got correct width, though a different value (96px), but I think that's because they render fonts differently.</sub>

Comment: If anyone is interested: [WhatsApp-chat-log-viewer (GitHub)](https://github.com/akinuri/WhatsApp-chat-log-viewer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs even when fonts are loaded externally. Check your snippet. First time it shows 94px for “Hello, World!” message, but on second click it is 98px (don’t forget to clear the cache if it shows correctly).

I was playing with it locally both with external and local files, different JQuery versions. The problem is that function fires before the fonts are loaded. To solve is just use the `window.onload` event:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $(".message").each(function () {
   console.log(this, this.clientWidth);
  });
};
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    background: gainsboro;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.message {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 275px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="message">Hi!</div>
<div class="message">Hello, World!</div>
<div class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
<div class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
<div class="message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
```

By the way, I could not reproduce the 96px in Firefox, only 94px, 98px and 97.7667px via element picker, don’t know why you have 96px.